# Conditional Tab order depending on data in particular cells

Tags: excel, vba, syntax, tabs

I have an order form in excel with 6 categories of equipment to be ordered. I am trying to make a custom tab order to move the active cell over to the next column which applies to the particular type of equipment chosen. For instance, if the user chose units I want to move from column E to F then skip G,H, & I and move directly over to K. After that I want to move to Column E in the next row. I only want this tab order to apply on rows that have a number in column B.

The way it would work would be like:

If the cell in column b of the active row is >=1 then

if cell in column e of the active row is blank go to column e then

if cell in column e of the active row is equal to units tab order E,F,K,M, next row E
else if cell in column e of the active row is equal to chairs tab order E,F,G,H,I,K,M next row E

{etc...}

I am having trouble with writing that meaning into code form.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I'm understanding correctly you want to replace the functionality of the tab key with your own. For that you want to use [`Application.OnKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197461%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

A simple example, in the VBA editor open Sheet1 and enter the following code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.OnKey "{TAB}", "TabIntercept"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Application.OnKey "{TAB}"
End Sub
```

Then insert a module and write a public sub like:

```
Public Sub TabIntercept()
    ActiveCell.Offset(2).Activate
End Sub
```

Now on Sheet1, tab will select the cell 2 below the current cell instead of one to the right as normal.

You can expand on this with if statements of course. Such as the following example, where tab acts normally, except if you have the cursor on Cell A2 and B2's value is 5, in which case it jumps to C3.

```
Public Sub TabIntercept()
    If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Sheet1.[A2]) Is Nothing And Sheet1.[B2] = 5 Then
      Sheet1.[C3].Activate
    Else
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

As a side note, if you want to support shift-tab and cycling your custom selections backwards you would need to write a second sub and add another call to the `OnKey` method. Something like `Application.OnKey "+{TAB}", "ReverseTabIntercept"`. The plus symbol indicates the shift key as you [can see in the documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197461%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: I am not getting the macro to fire unless i click into the dev. tab and choose to execute the tabintercept macro, I copied your activate, deactivate and tab intercept macros... I appreciate the help!

Comment: Are you sure you have Worksheet_Activate and Worksheet_Deactivate in the worksheet object? Set a breakpoint in Worksheet_Activate to see if it triggers. It should trigger when you switch to that sheet from another sheet. The idea is that it enables the keyboard intercept when that spreadsheet is active/visible and disables it on other spreadsheets. You could also move the `Application.OnKey` code into a public sub in your module and enable it manually for testing.